# How to get useWindowDimensions to work with useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I need to keep track of the size of a div. When a user resizes the browser window, it should trigger a function called `setDivResize` that just saves the size of a div...

```
useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch(setDivResize)
},[useWindowDimensions().width])
```

However this does not seem to work. How can I trigger `setDivResize` when the user resizes the browser?

Comment: how about destructuring `width` from hook and having it in the deps ? `const {width} = useWindowDimensions() .....  useEffect(()=>..,[width])`

Comment: Can you share `useWindowDimensions` - guessing the issue is somewhere in your hook

Answer (score 0):

Per the [useWindowDimensions doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions), you can do this:

```
const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

And then use `width` in the useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(setDivResize)
},[width])
```